# Room database - Query with string manipulation

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I need to make a select query with android Room.
I have a table with 3 columns: "id", "pathOfFile", "rank"
The "pathOfFile" is like "file:///path/to/file.png"

I want to select all the path that have a the last name of the file equal "file.png"

I write this

```
SELECT  pathOfFile  
FROM FilePaths   
WHERE replace(pathOfFile, rtrim(pathOfFile, replace(pathOfFile, '/', '')), '') in ("file.png", ....)   
ORDER BY rank
```

If I execute this query on a SqliteBrowser on my PC, I don't have problems.
When I write

```
@Query(SELECT  pathOfFile FROM FilePaths  WHERE replace(pathOfFile, rtrim(pathOfFile, replace(pathOfFile, '/', '')), '') in (:filePaths)  ORDER BY rank
```

Android Studio give me an error " expected, got 'replace'" after the WHERE keyword.

How can I make query on DB like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. It seems to be a bug of android studio editor.

The editor give me an error in "replace" keyword, but when I click "Run", the build is complected with success.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simplify it to this room query?

```
SELECT pathOfFile  
FROM FilePaths   
WHERE pathOfFile LIKE :filePath
ORDER BY rank
```

...where parameter filePath is passed as `"%" + actualFilePathEnding`

Comment: No, because :filePath is a list.
Similar to   "WHERE pathOfFile LIKE IN (:filePath1, :filePath2)"
But this isn't a valid query